# String matching and extraction

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a string like "ab.cde.fg.hi", and I want to split it into two strings.

1. "ab.cde.fg"
2. ".hi"

How to do so?  I got some code written that will get me the 2nd string but how do I retrieve the remaining?

```
$mystring = "ab.cde.fg";
$mystring =~ m/.*(\..+)/;
print "$1\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my ($first, $second) = $string =~ /(.*)(\..*)/;
```

You can also use `split`:

```
my ($first, $second) = split /(?=\.[^.]+$)/, $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you aren’t looking for...

```
($name,$path,$suffix) = File::Basename::fileparse($fullname,@suffixlist);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @parts = /(.*)\.(.*)/s;

my @parts = split /\.(?!.*\.)/s;

my @parts = split /\.(?=[^.]*\z)/s;
```

**Update**: I misread. The "." should be included in the second part, but it's not in the above. The above should be:

```
my @parts = /(.*)(\..*)/s;

my @parts = split /(?=\.(?!.*\.))/s;

my @parts = split /(?=\.[^.]*\z)/s;
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that the last two split the `$_` string

Comment: @eugene y, All 6 operate on `$_`, although all 6 can easily be adjusted to work on a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

To promote my idea to use rindex to get

```
   1) "ab.cde.fg" 
   2) ".hi"
```

from `"ab.cde.fg.hi"`, I wrote this script to make experiments easier:

```
  use strict;
  use diagnostics;
  use warnings;
  use English;

  my @tests = (
      [ 'ab.cde.fg.hi', 'ab.cde.fg|.hi' ]
    , [ 'abxcdexfg.hi', 'abxcdexfg|.hi' ]
  );
  for my $test (@tests) {
    my $src = $test->[0];
    my $exp = $test->[1];
    printf "-----|%s| ==> |%s|-----\n", $src, $exp;
    for my $op (
        [ 'ikegami 1' , sub { shift =~ /(.*)\.(.*)/s; } ]
      , [ 'ikegami 2' , sub { split( /\.(?!.*\.\z)/s, shift) } ]
      , [ 'rindex'    , sub { my $p = rindex( $_[0], '.' );
                              (   substr($_[0], 0, $p)
                                , substr($_[0], $p)
                              ); }
        ]
    ) {
      my ($head, $tail) = $op->[1]( $src );
      my $res = join '|', ($head, $tail);
      my $ok  = $exp eq $res ? 'ok' : "fail: $exp expected.";
      printf "%12s: %-20s => %-20s : %s\n", $op->[0], $src, $res, $ok;
    }
  }
```

output:

```
-----|ab.cde.fg.hi| ==> |ab.cde.fg|.hi|-----
   ikegami 1: ab.cde.fg.hi         => ab.cde.fg|hi         : fail: ab.cde.fg|.hi expected.
   ikegami 2: ab.cde.fg.hi         => ab|cde               : fail: ab.cde.fg|.hi expected.
      rindex: ab.cde.fg.hi         => ab.cde.fg|.hi        : ok
-----|abxcdexfg.hi| ==> |abxcdexfg|.hi|-----
   ikegami 1: abxcdexfg.hi         => abxcdexfg|hi         : fail: abxcdexfg|.hi expected.
   ikegami 2: abxcdexfg.hi         => abxcdexfg|hi         : fail: abxcdexfg|.hi expected.
      rindex: abxcdexfg.hi         => abxcdexfg|.hi        : ok
```